# Позиционирование блоков CSS

Tags: css, веб-программирование, позиционирование

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
main {
    flex: 1 0 auto; 
  } 
#logo{ 
font-size: 45px;
color: #FFF; 
}  
       
footer{  
height: 45px;  
background: #f2784b;       
}                  
   
nav .nav-wrapper{ 
    background: #f2784b;
}  
.tabs .tab{   
    text-transform: none; 
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
.tabs .tab.disabled a{
    color: #4e4e4e/*#ff956e*/;
}
.tabs .tab a:hover{
    color: #717070/*#ffc2ac*/;
}  
.tabs .tab a{
    color: #4e4e4e/*#ff956e*/; 
}
.tabs .indicator{  
    background-color: #969696;
}   

table{

    border: 1px solid #000;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, 
body {
  height: 100%;
} 
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}  
content { 
  flex: 1 0 auto;
} 
footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;

}
table{ 
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
} 
td {border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fffbf2;
}  
th{     
    border-radius: 0;
    background: #00b16a;
    color: #FFF;
} 

.clearfix:before, 
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
 
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Name</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a id="logo" class="brand-logo center">Name</a>
    </div> 
      </nav>

    <div class="col s12">
      <ul class="tabs">
          <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test1"><i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i> Расписание</a></li> 
      </ul> 
      </div>
<content>
    <div id="test1">
       <div class="row">    
<div class="col l6 m6 s12">
 <table class="bordered centered">
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th>Понедельник, 5 сентября 2016</th>
 <th>Задано</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
 <tbody>
</table> 
   <table class="bordered centered">
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th>Вторник, 6 сентября 2016</th>
 <th>Задано</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
 <tbody>
</table>
<table class="bordered centered">
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th>Среда,
7 сентября 2016</th>
<th>Задано</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td> 
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
 <tbody>
</table>
           </div>
<div class="col l6 m6 s12 offset-l6">
<table class="bordered centered">
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th>Четверг,
8 сентября 2016</th>
<th>Задано</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td> 
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
 <tbody>
</table>
       <table class="bordered centered">
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th>Пятница,
9 сентября 2016</th>
<th>Задано</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td> 
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
 <tbody>
</table>
       <table class="bordered centered">
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th>Суббота,
10 сентября 2016</th>
<th>Задано</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td> 
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Урок</td>
<td>Домашнее задание</td>
    </tr>
 <tbody>
</table>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
  
        </content>
    <footer>
    </footer>
      </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Имеются два дива. Второй див отступает от первого. [image: Так быть не должно]
Необходимо сделать так, чтобы оба дива располагались параллельно, на одном уровне.

P.S.
Используется фреймворк [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/).
Для того, чтобы увидеть проблему, необходимо раскрыть область кода (При стандартном размере области кода дивы принимают необходимый мне вид)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас на колонке стоит класс

```
<div class="col l6 m6 s12 offset-l6">
```

Уберите offset-l6 и они на одном уровне будут

Comment: Спасибо огромное) Внимательности мне не хватает, видимо...

Comment: @Марк Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).